# Switches different paths

Tags: switches

[image]

I would like to know what switch options are available under condiotions when voltage zero is less than 4 volts. Then voltage source 2 (blue) is connected to the load. Otherwise voltage source zero and voltage source one (green)  are connected in series to the load.

Comment: Sounds like a relay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a relay and have the relay open and turn on the load and then off for the green on